# Postgresql case and testing boolean fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean, case

First: I'm running postgresql 8.2 and testing my queries on pgAdmin.

I have a table with some fields, say:

```
mytable(
  id integer,
  mycheck boolean,
  someText varchar(200));
```

Now, I want a query similary to this:

```
 select id,
  case when mycheck then (select name from tableA)
       else (select name from tableB) end as mySpecialName,
  someText;
```

I tried to run and get this:

```
ERROR: CASE types character varying and boolean cannot be matched
SQL state: 42804
```

And  even trying to fool postgresql with

```
case (mycheck::integer) when 0 then
```

didn't work.

So, my question is: since sql doesn't have if, only case, how I'm suppose to do an if with a boolean field?

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is a mismatch in your values (expressions after `then` and `else`), not your predicate (expression after `when`).  Make sure that `select name from tableA` and `select name from tableB` return the same result type.  `mycheck` is supposed to be a boolean.

I ran this query on PostgreSQL 9.0beta2, and (except for having to add `from mytable` to the SELECT statement as well as creating tables `tableA` and `tableB`), and it didn't yield any type errors.  However, I get an error message much like the one you described when I run the following:

```
select case when true
           then 1
           else 'hello'::text 
       end;
```

The above yields:

```
ERROR:  CASE types text and integer cannot be matched
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this fine on PostgreSQL 8:

```
select id,
 case when mycheck = true then (...)
      else (...),
 someText;
```